Why do physicists want to apply the energy conservation law to the entire universe, when it is immune to falsification?
General Relativity (GR) itself is an approximation for space- and time-like phenomena. It does not make philosophical statements about reality and could potentially be replaced in the future. The energy conservation law applies to closed systems, specifically local systems within the universe that are experimentally testable. It cannot be applied to the universe as a whole because such an application would not be accessible to experiment, as Prof. Wagner from the University of Vienna correctly notes.
So why do some physicists believe that the Big Bang theory—which is based on extrapolating GR backwards to a singularity—is incompatible with the energy conservation law? The energy conservation law can only be applied to local phenomena because these are the only ones that can be tested. Anything else becomes immune to falsification (Popper).
GR does not provide definitive statements about space and time but rather yields approximate calculations that are accurate under specific conditions. If we could philosophically secure the singularity as a concept "before" space and time and deduce the energy conservation law from it, there would be no issue. If this cannot be done, then we simply have two models that only appear problematic if we extend the energy conservation law to the universe as a whole and invoke the Noether theorem to argue against it. But this extension doesn't make sense in the first place.
I don’t quite understand the problem here. Can someone explain this to me?

I don't understand something basic about this question. You say a certain idea is not falsifiable, but then you also say "physicists want to apply it". But application implies it can fail to agree with observation, hence is falsifiable. Please clarify.

What did you that mean, not consistent with observation? What observation in the universe would violate the law of energy if the law of energy were applied to the whole universe? These are mathematical speculations, without predictions. So I don't understand the point of it.

The point is, if an idea is not falsifiable, it doesn't matter what you replace it with, it will also not be falsifiable. The non-falsifiability comes from the inability to test the idea against experiment. Hence what a physicist believes and is non-falsifiable is irrelevant. He can only replace that belief with another non-falsifiable belief. In other words, it is not related to his physics practice at all, it is just a personal opinion. So I don't understand what bearing this question can have on the actual physics. Would the idea that energy isn't conserved be testable??

So then do you agree with me that the question about the law of energy in relation to the universe makes no sense? I wanted to know that, because that was also Paul Wagner's opinion. A physicist just tried to explain that to me and I was surprised.

I agree that when talking about the entire universe, it is very easy to postulate things that sound scientific, but really aren't. As Richard Feynman once put it, on a related matter of how can we know if the entire universe would obey time translation symmetry: "...but we don't start the universe".

The conservation of energy of the universe is not immune from falsification. At least, not in the way scientists mean it.

@Dale That's just an assertion, and it has to be justified. You can examine the question philosophically, yes, but you can't do an experiment with the whole universe, how could that work?

Every experiment we do tests the universe. When scientists say that the energy of the universe is conserved they mean that there is a Lagrangian describing the large scale structure of the universe which is time translation invariant. That is indeed testable, and is falsified. The fact that there is no conserved energy on cosmological scales is a well known consequence of the FLRW spacetime. Since it is falsified, your claim that it is non falsifiable is wrong

@Tal I know that, but it is a speculative extraploration, it has nothing to do with a clear refutation. On the other hand, this question can be examined philosophically in detail. For me, this is not pure science and is pseudoscience. I can do an extraploration of  all sorts of things. The general theory of relativity only gives approximate values ​​for space and time-like phenomena.


tenebris in kux wrote: "It cannot be applied to the universe as a whole because such an application would not be accessible to experiment"

This runs under the assumption of the Copernican principle which says that

the Copernican principle wrote: "Observations from the Earth are representative of observations from the average position in the universe"

